# How to install GRASS in QGIS Dufour?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

How do I install GRASS to run in QGIS 2.0.1?  GRASS is not listed in the Plugin Manager and attempting to access it via the Processing Toolbox gives me the following error:

[image: GRASS error]

Comment: Well, if you click "Click here" what happens then? I work with MacOSX but as far as I remember installed the QGIS intsaller in windows both: QGIS and Grass. Otherwise you could try to install Grass separately and then load the Grass plugin in QGIS. regards, Jörn

Comment: So maybe you didn't install GRASS? GRASS is __not__ a QGIS plugin. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASS_GIS

Comment: what os do you use. in case of windows-os, whch qgis-installer did you use?

Comment: 'Click here' just takes me to the user guide which is of no further help in resolving the problem.  I'm using Windows 7 and used the standalone installer.

Comment: This appears to be a known issue: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8627 so perhaps you could try the OSGEO4W installer?

Comment: That would explain it, thanks!  I will try the OSGEO4W installer.

Comment: Standalone installer version 3 install grass with no problems

Comment: Gerardo, thank you - it worked :)  Please can you post your comment as an answer below for others who are seeking a solution to the same problem.